# View to Table Relationship in EF Core 3.1

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, view

Using SQL Server with Entity Framework Core 3.1. I have a view that I need to join to a table. This obviously works fine within SQL Server. But I can't get the relationship correctly defined in EF. Logically, this should be possible. I'm found no online documentation that indicates it is not possible.

I've created a small VisualStudio project that exhibits the issue. These are all the files in the project. It's contrived, but very simple. I'm using "database first" so this example matches my real application.

Two entities that map to tables:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ViewJoinIssue.Entities
{
    public class ArticleEntity
    {
        public int ArticleId { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Author { get; set; }

        public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ArticleTagEntity> Tags { get; set; } = new List<ArticleTagEntity>();
    }
}
```

```
namespace ViewJoinIssue.Entities
{
    public class ArticleTagEntity
    {
        public int ArticleTagId { get; set; }

        public string Tag { get; set; }

        public int ArticleId { get; set; }
        public ArticleEntity Article { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Another class for an item returned by a query on a view:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ViewJoinIssue.Entities
{
    public class ArticleViewItem
    {
        public int ArticleId { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ArticleTagEntity> Tags { get; set; } = new List<ArticleTagEntity>();
    }
}
```

Configuration classes for each of those:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using ViewJoinIssue.Entities;

namespace ViewJoinIssue.EntityConfiguration
{
    public class ArticleConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ArticleEntity>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ArticleEntity> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(e => e.ArticleId);

            builder.Property(e => e.ArticleId)
                   .HasColumnName("ArticleId")
                   .HasColumnType("int")
                   .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            builder.Property(e => e.Title)
                   .HasColumnName("Title")
                   .HasColumnType("varchar(256)")
                   .HasMaxLength(256)
                   .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(e => e.Author)
                   .HasColumnName("Author")
                   .HasColumnType("varchar(64)")
                   .HasMaxLength(64)
                   .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(e => e.PublishDate)
                   .HasColumnName("PublishDate")
                   .HasColumnType("datetime")
                   .IsRequired();

            builder.ToTable("Article");

            builder.HasMany(e => e.Tags)
                   .WithOne(e => e.Article)
                   .HasForeignKey(e => e.ArticleId);
        }
    }
}
```

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using ViewJoinIssue.Entities;

namespace ViewJoinIssue.EntityConfiguration
{
    public class ArticleTagConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ArticleTagEntity>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ArticleTagEntity> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(e => e.ArticleTagId);

            builder.Property(e => e.ArticleTagId)
                   .HasColumnName("ArticleTagId")
                   .HasColumnType("int")
                   .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            builder.Property(e => e.Tag)
                   .HasColumnName("Tag")
                   .HasColumnType("varchar(32)")
                   .HasMaxLength(32)
                   .IsRequired();

            builder.ToTable("ArticleTag");

            builder.HasOne(e => e.Article)
                   .WithMany(e => e.Tags)
                   .HasForeignKey(e => e.ArticleId);
        }
    }
}
```

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using ViewJoinIssue.Entities;

namespace ViewJoinIssue.EntityConfiguration
{
    public class ArticleViewItemConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ArticleViewItem>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ArticleViewItem> builder)
        {
            builder.HasNoKey();

            builder.Property(e => e.ArticleId)
                   .HasColumnName("ArticleId")
                   .HasColumnType("int")
                   .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            builder.Property(e => e.Title)
                   .HasColumnName("Title")
                   .HasColumnType("varchar(256)")
                   .HasMaxLength(256)
                   .IsRequired();

            builder.ToView("vwArticles");

            builder.HasMany(e => e.Tags)
                   .WithOne()
                   .HasPrincipalKey(e => e.ArticleId);
        }
    }
}
```

The database context:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ViewJoinIssue.Entities;
using ViewJoinIssue.EntityConfiguration;

namespace ViewJoinIssue
{
    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=(local)\\SQLSERVER2017;Initial Catalog=Articles;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Packet Size=4096");

            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ArticleConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ArticleTagConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ArticleViewItemConfiguration());

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public virtual DbSet<ArticleEntity> Articles { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ArticleTagEntity> ArticleTags { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ArticleViewItem> ArticleViewItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the simple console program:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ViewJoinIssue
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var context = new DatabaseContext();

            var viewItems = context.ArticleViewItems.ToList();

            Console.WriteLine($"Found {viewItems.Count} items.");
        }
    }
}
```

You can actually compile that and run it to see the error I'm getting. No actual database is required.

On this statement in ArticleViewItemConfiguration ...

```
            builder.HasMany(e => e.Tags)
                   .WithOne()
                   .HasPrincipalKey(e => e.ArticleId);
```

... it throws this exception:

```
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.SetOrAddForeignKey(ForeignKey foreignKey, InternalEntityTypeBuilder principalEntityTypeBuilder, IReadOnlyList`1 dependentProperties, Key principalKey, String navigationToPrincipalName, Nullable`1 isRequired, Nullable`1 configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.CreateForeignKey(InternalEntityTypeBuilder principalEntityTypeBuilder, IReadOnlyList`1 dependentProperties, Key principalKey, String navigationToPrincipalName, Nullable`1 isRequired, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.HasRelationshipInternal(EntityType targetEntityType, Key principalKey, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.HasRelationship(EntityType principalEntityType, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder`1.HasMany[TRelatedEntity](Expression`1 navigationExpression)
   at ViewJoinIssue.EntityConfiguration.ArticleViewItemConfiguration.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder`1 builder) in C:\Work\PostBidShip\Code\ViewJoinIssue\EntityConfiguration\ArticleViewItemConfiguration.cs:line 26
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration[TEntity](IEntityTypeConfiguration`1 configuration)
   at ViewJoinIssue.DatabaseContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) in C:\Work\PostBidShip\Code\ViewJoinIssue\DatabaseContext.cs:line 20
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelCustomizer.Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.CheckState()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TEntity>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at ViewJoinIssue.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Work\PostBidShip\Code\ViewJoinIssue\Program.cs:line 12
```

It appears that it is trying to "set or add" a foreign key. But that won't work with a view, since it has no key.

I have removed the ".HasPrincipleKey" method call, but I still get the same exception. Logically, it seems I need to tell EF with property to use for the join, since there isn't a foreign key (it's a view).

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? Or perhaps this is an EF bug. I've found no help online; I've searched every way I can think of. Most of the examples using a view are very simple; most are just for returning a count.

Thanks!!

Comment: It's by design (not a bug). Is the `ArticleId` column **unique** in the underlying database view?

Comment: Yes, in this case it would be. In my real application it is.

Comment: So was there any solution to this? Since we have same issue want to add "link" between Table and View in EF core...

Comment: I believe I made it work like this... Instead of this in `ArticleViewItemConfiguration`:

`builder.HasNoKey()`

Do this instead:

`builder.HasKey(e => e.ArticleId)`

Since the `ArticleId` is configured `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` and I never do an add via the view, it seems to work.